# CSS - Creating a custom arrow

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to create a custom arrow in `CSS` that looks like the image below.
Ideally I want to create this by overlaying two shapes a triangle and a rectangle (maybe using `CSS` `:after` and `:before`) but I'm not too savvy when it comes to `CSS` so I have been struggling.I started by just using borders but doesn't look like it is going to work

So far I just have:

```css
.arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: why not use an image that you can adjust in size, rather then trying to draw an arrow using css?

Comment: Because I do not want to add it as an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too hard to make using the `:before` pseudo element and some transforms:

```css
.container {
   padding: 100px;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  width: 75px;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 100px solid #000;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(100%) translateX(31%);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.

```css
.arrow{
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}

.arrow::before{
  content: "";
  height:50px;
  width:80px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: -100%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-160%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one rectangle and then add triangle on top with `:before` pseudo-element and that is it.

```css
.arrow {
  width: 36px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #3F3F3F;
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 40px 40px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #3F3F3F transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain and demonstrate:

A CSS arrow is created by coloring 1 border side, and then moving the other 3 sides in towards the middle of the shape as transparent so they don't show but cut the remaining colored side into a triangle. The shorthand for this is TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT. So to make a triangle pointing upwards you use the third property or bottom.

Using pseudo elements (incase you want the arrow added to another element) you need `content:''` to "create" the pseudo element. I've set them as `display: block` so that they are in the flow and interact with eachother (rather than being laid on top of one another).

By giving the rectangle `position: relative` you can then use `left: 30px` (half of the triangle width) to position it in the middle of the triangle.

```css
.arrowWrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 60px 60px 60px;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  /* border-color: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT; */
}

.arrowWrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrowWrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lifted and modified from http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/:

```css
#eq-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 104px solid blue;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}

#rectangle {
   width: 40px; 
   height: 80px;
   background: blue;
   margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="eq-triangle"></div>
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```